# Method won't print results to the console

Tags: c#

I have a program where I load information about dogs. Then I need to find the oldest dogs of specific breed. The problem is, my program doesn't print anything.

Here is the code:

```
private static int findOldestAge(Dog[] dogs, string breed)
{
    int maxAge = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dogCount; i++)
    {
        if (dogs[i].Age > maxAge)
            maxAge = dogs[i].Age;
    }
    return maxAge;
}

private static Dog[] findOldestDogs(Dog[] dogs, string breed, int age)
{
    Dog[] oldestDogs = new Dog[MaxNumberOfDogs];

    for (int i = 0; i < dogCount; i++)
    {
        if (dogs[i].Age == age)
            oldestDogs[oldestDogCount] = dogs[i];
        }
        return oldestDogs;
    }

static void PrintDogsToConsole(Dog[] dogs, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vardas: {0}\nMikroschemos ID: {1}\nSvoris: {2}\nAmžius: {3}\nVeislė: {4}\nSavininkas: {5}\nTelefonas: {6}\nVakcinacijos data: {7}\nAgresyvus: {8}", dogs[i].Name, dogs[i].ChipId, dogs[i].Weight, dogs[i].Age, dogs[i].Breed, dogs[i].Owner, dogs[i].Phone, dogs[i].VaccinationDate, dogs[i].Aggressive);
    }
}
```

This is the main method. I'm pretty sure the data is loaded fine, because it would print all the information if I want.

```
Dog[] dogs = new Dog[MaxNumberOfDogs];
Console.WriteLine("Which breed dogs count?");
breed = Console.ReadLine();
Dog[] oldestDogs = findOldestDogs(dogs, breed, findOldestAge(dogs, breed));
PrintDogsToConsole(oldestDogs, oldestDogCount);
```

Comment: Where is the `PrintDogsToConsole` method? Does your program throw any errors, or does it just complete with no output?

Comment: No errors. It just complete with no output.

Comment: FWIW you never use the `breed` parameter either.

Comment: `dogs.Where(d=>d.Age==dogs.Max(w=>w.Age))` if you want to replace your novel with a single line of code.

Comment: Where is dogCount set?  Is it set before you call findOldestAge and findOldestDogs?

Comment: Yes. It prints the right number if I want.

Comment: `PrintDogsToConsole(oldestDogs, oldestDogCount);` I don't see you assign a value to `oldestDogCount` anywhere (or even declare it).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I declared and assigned value to this variable.

Comment: Error has been already spotted out (at least one of them). Now let's debug your code to see what happens when you use oldestDogCount...

Comment: `Dog[] dogs = new Dog[MaxNumberOfDogs];` this is empty array of dog. where do you set the dogs. (this is just some number of empty dogs)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti What error?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it's not empty. I could send you whole project file if you are willing to check.

Comment: oldestDogCount for sure and I'd also check dogCount. Easier to debug step by step (try with more than one dog) than to explain

Comment: What is oldestDogCount in the Main method? It is not defined anywhere

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was defined oldestDogCount, but forgot to type "++" in findOldestDogs method. That's why oldestDogCount value was always. Stupid mistake. Thanks everyone for help/

Answer (score 1):

In this Line you are creating array:
`Dog[] dogs = new Dog[MaxNumberOfDogs];`
Yes, this array isn't empty, it contains `MaxNumberOfDogs` Dog objects.
But your `Dog Object`'s properties are `null` or `default` (initialized in constructor or in declaration).

Then you sent it to `findOldestDogs` method:

You use `Age` property of `dogs[i]` object, that hasn't value ( or if it is type of `int` and initialized, value will be `0` ).
Because of that your `dogs[i].Age > maxAge` will no't return `true` and `oldestDogs` will reamin empty.